# Rails - Flash not showing depending on how I access the sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect, heroku, flash-message

I'm following the Rails Tutorial and I'm having an issue that's been driving me crazy. I want to display a flash message saying "Check your email" after signing up, and redirect to root_url.

If I type the url (my-app.com/signup) and access the sign up page directly, the flash message is here after redirecting.
But if I access the sign up page by clicking and navigating through my app, I'm redirected to root_url as expected but there's no flash message.

I have this issue both on C9 and Heroku. I checked the logs and maybe it's just a coincidence but everytime the flash does not appear I have the following message: "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity."

Do you have an idea where this is coming from or how to solve this issue please?

Here are some samples of my code:

*users_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  [...]

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    @user.send_activation_email
    flash[:success] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

*application_layout.html.erb*

```
 <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
 <% end %>
```

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'password_resets/new'

get 'password_resets/edit'

get 'user_sessions/new'

root 'static_pages#home'

# Static pages routes
get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'

# Users sign up and log in/out routes
get '/signup', to:'users#new'
post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
get    '/login',   to: 'user_sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'user_sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'user_sessions#destroy'

resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

Let me know if you need more information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

Okay I just found why it behaved that way and how to solve the issue.

Apparently the "protect_from_forgery" line in the users_controller removes session data, flash information, and associated cookies with each request that fails verification (click the following link for more info https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery/).

I removed that line and added

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

in the sign up form layout and it worked again.

---